# Remove image hover effect

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on this wordpress site using the Bridge theme (by Qode): http://www.musegroupreno.com/plp/

There are images in the smaller squares on the home page that have a hover effect. I am using the Masonry Gallery (a Qode addon to the Visual Composer plugin) that makes me set each square/rectangle type to either have a solid overlay/background color or not. All small squares (text and image) are the same. The problem is that we want the text squares to have a pink background and the image squares to not transition to pink on mouse hover.

We want small square images to look and act like the tall rectangle does where if you hover over it, nothing changes. This happens because the overlay/background color is set to be have `opacity:0;`. If I do this for the small squares I lose the pink behind the text squares but the images look great.

In the existing system, there is no way to set an individual class for image/text square or each square separately.

**So what I can't figure out is how to remove the hover state transition so that it doesn't cover the image in pink on mouseover but leaves the background pink in the text squares.**

It looks like it is the `.masonry_gallery_item_inner` element that changes the opacity. I think that it is shifting the background-color but am unsure. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.masonry_gallery_item.standard:hover .masonry_gallery_item_inner {
    opacity: 0;
}

.masonry_gallery_item.square_small .masonry_gallery_item_inner {
    background-color: rgba(255,235,233,1);
}
```

This is working the same way you need.
May be you are setting opacity:0; to class ".masonry_gallery_item.square_small .masonry_gallery_item_inner" and that is why you are losing the pink background.

Comment: You are my savior! I have spent way to much time trying other things and it was so simple! Thank you!